# Save file to output folder creating it if it does not exist

Tags: python, path, io

I'm using the [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) library to handle I/O in my script. I read a file with the path:

```
PosixPath('input/ADE/data_f34.dat')
```

The parent folder `input/` is fixed, but neither the sub-folder (`ADE`) nor the file's name are fixed, i.e., they change with each iteration. I need a general to store a *new* file with the *same name*, to the path:

```
PosixPath('output/ADE/data_f34.dat')
```

I.e., respecting the sub-folder and the file's names, but changing `input/` to `output/`. The `output` folder always exists, but I don't know a priori if the sub-folder `output/ADE/` exists so I need to create if it does not. If a file with the same name already exists, I can simply overwrite it.

What is the proper way to handle this with `pathlib`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```py
import pathlib

src = pathlib.PosixPath('input/ADE/data_f34.dat')
dst = pathlib.Path('output', *src.parts[1:])
dst.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
with open(dst, 'w') as d, open(src) as s:
    d.write(s.read())
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [relative_to](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.relative_to):

```py
from pathlib import PosixPath

filename = PosixPath('input/ADE/data_f34.dat')
output_dir = PosixPath('output')

path = output_dir / filename.relative_to('input')
path.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)

print(path)
```

Prints

```py
output/ADE/data_f34.dat
```

Comment: You might want to add the rest of the code to safely create parent directories.